# roscore hangs up in the middle

Tags: raspberrypi, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I`m quite new to ROS and Linux, I need to use ROS to communicate between VICON system and Crazyflie. When I tried to run the rosrun, it works but hangs up in the middle at *started core service [/rosout]* . I wait for 15 minutes but there is nothing new. Could you tell me what is happening? Here is what actually happens on the terminal console:

```
pi@pi-desktop:~$ roscore
... logging to /home/pi/.ros/log/1e8ee47c-1945-11e7-8cfb-b827eb1fc882/roslaunch-pi-desktop-2196.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://pi-desktop:43110/
ros_comm version 1.12.6


SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.6

NODES

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [2209]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://pi-desktop:11311/

setting /run_id to 1e8ee47c-1945-11e7-8cfb-b827eb1fc882
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [2222]
started core service [/rosout]
^C[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

My Ubuntu version is 16.04 and I'm using ROS Kinetic. Actually, I downloaded an image with ROS pre-installed on this website of germanrobot http://www.german-robot.com/2016/05/26/raspberry-pi-sd-card-image/ as suggested by ROS for my Raspberry 3.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258558/roscore-hangs-up-in-the-middle/) by [thanhvu94](https://answers.ros.org/users/29865/thanhvu94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2017-04-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-04-05**:
What are you doing and what do you expect? Like others have said, `roscore` doesn't do much in the foreground and you're not going to see much happening. It sets up the infrastructure for your system. You'll see stuff happening when you run other nodes.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-04-05**:
In other words, `roscore` is doing *exactly* what it's supposed to, there's no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Roscore, same as rosnodes are applications, in linux, you are starting those in a terminal windows, those can be abruptly terminated by doing on the focus gained terminal Control+C  I see in the windows you are doing that

check this line

> ...started core service [/rosout]

until that line everything was ok, roscore was runing as expected... but then you do:

> **^C**[rosout-1] killing on exit

> ...[master] killing on exit

so you are actually killing the roscore

---

Originally posted by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) with karma: 424 on 2017-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeoker](https://answers.ros.org/users/32878/jeoker/) on 2017-12-05**:
I'm facing the same issue. So do you mean that after running roscore, the console will just end up with showing "started core service [/rosout]"? If so, how do I give further command to my raspberrypi?